# Efficient way to find $a$ in $c = 6a\mod n$

Tags: modular-arithmetic

Given $c$ and $n$ in $c = 6a\mod n$, how can I find the lowest positive integer value for $a$?

I could find it iteratively by rewriting as $\displaystyle a = \frac{c + xn}{6}$ and increasing $x$ until $a$ is an integer, but I would prefer a more efficient solution.  Is there another way to do this?

Edit:  Combined two variables.

Here is an example:  $3 = 6a\mod 11$

Comment: If $\gcd(n,6)=1$ then you actually calculate $\frac{b-c}{6}\pmod n$, and the result is $a$.

Comment: The Euclidean Algorithm is a pretty standard way to do this.

Comment: And if it's not then your equation might have no solutions at all (e.g. $n = 6$ removes $a$ from the equation altogether).

Comment: @jnm2: Do you also know $\gcd(n,6)$?

Comment: Yes, $n$ will be a prime 5 or greater.  But$ \frac{b-c}{6}$ gave me a fractional result.  I'm looking for an integer.

Comment: @jnm2: The point is to compute the multiplicative inverse of $6$ modulo $n$, not the rational number. You can do this via the Extended Euclidean algorithm, when $\gcd(6,n)=1$.

Comment: @jnm2: Since $1 = 2(6)-11$, then $(2)(6)\equiv 1\pmod{11}$; hence, from $3\equiv 6a\pmod{11}$, multiplying through by $2$ you get $6\equiv a\pmod{11}$ and you are done.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**First, general comments.**

The congruence
$$Ax\equiv c \pmod{n}$$
has a solution $x$ if and only if $\gcd(A,n)|c$. If it does, the standard method is to use the extended Euclidean algorithm to find integers $r$ and $s$ such that
$$d = Ar + ns$$
(where $d=\gcd(A,n)$); then multiply by $\frac{c}{d}$ (an integer, since $d|c$) to get
$$c = A\left(\frac{rc}{d}\right) + n\left(\frac{sc}{d}\right).$$
So one solution is $a=\frac{rc}{d}$. Finding the remainder of $\frac{rc}{d}$ modulo $n$ can be done by direct division. If $d\gt 1$, then you still need to make sure that there is no smaller division by comparing with $\frac{n}{d}$, since given any particular solution to $Ax\equiv c\pmod{n}$, then $x\pm\frac{n}{d}$ is also a solution.

The extended Euclidean algorithm is pretty efficient, but even so there are a few tweaks that can be done to make it even more so (e.g., instead of always requiring the remainder to be positive, you can require that the remainder lie between $-\frac{n}{2}$ and $\frac{n}{2}$). The other steps are pretty efficient as well.

---

*Added.* If, as you indicate in comments, the modulus is prime, you can also use Gauss's method. Write the fraction you want (in this case, $\frac{c}{A}$), and multiply numerator and denominator by the smallest $k$ such that $Ak\gt n$ (or such that $Ak$ has a small remainder in absolute value modulo $n$); then reduce and repeat until you get to a denominator equal to $1$.

---

**Now, your particular issue.**

However, the case of $A=6$ and prime modulus is particularly simple, since every prime other than $3$ is either congruent to $1$ or to $-1$ modulo $6$. So write $n=6k\pm 1$, and use $k$:
For the example you write, note that $11 = 2\times 6 - 1$:
$$a\equiv \frac{3}{6} = \frac{2\times 3}{2\times 6} = \frac{6}{12} \equiv \frac{6}{1} \equiv 6\pmod{11}.$$
For another, say you want to solve
$$7\equiv 6a\pmod{43}.$$
Since $43 = 6\times 7 + 1$, then we have
$$a \equiv \frac{7}{6} =\frac{7\times 7}{7\times 6} \equiv \frac{49}{42}\equiv \frac{6}{-1}= -6 \equiv 37\pmod{43}.$$
Etc.

**In summary.** For a prime modulus $n\gt 3$, divide $n$ by $6$, and write $n=6k\pm 1$. If $n=6k-1$, then $a\equiv ck\pmod{n}$, so then you just need to divide $ck$ by $n$ to get the remainder. If $n=6k+1$, then $a\equiv -ck$, so find the remainder for $-ck$ instead.

Comment: [See here](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/174687/242) for more on Gauss's algorithm.

Answer (score 1):

**HINT** $\:$ If it is solvable then you can cancel $\rm\:gcd(6,n)\:,\:$  yielding $\rm\: d\:a\ = b\ (mod\ m)\:$ for $\rm\:d\:$ dividing $6\:.\:$ Now simply multiply through by $\rm\:1/d\ (mod\ m)\:,\:$ which is *easily directly* computable, namely

$\rm\displaystyle\qquad\qquad\quad\: m\:\equiv\: \pm 1\ \ (mod\ d)\ \ \Rightarrow\ \ \frac{1}d\:\equiv\: \frac{1\mp m}{d}\ \ (mod\ m)\:.\ $

E.g. $\rm\displaystyle\qquad\  {\color{red}{25}}\:\equiv\: {\color{red}+1}\ \ (mod\ 6)\ \ \Rightarrow\ \ \frac{1}6\:\equiv\:\frac{1{\color{red}{-25}}}6\:\equiv -4\ \ (mod\ 25)$

E.g. $\rm\displaystyle\quad\ \ \ \ {\color{red}{23}}\:\equiv {\color{red}{-}}1\ \ (mod\ 6)\ \ \Rightarrow\ \ \frac{1}6\:\equiv\:\frac{1{\color{red}{+23}}}6\:\equiv\ \ 4\ \ \ (mod\ 23)$

Note that the reason this works out so simply is due to the fact that the only numbers coprime to $6$ are those $\rm\:\equiv \pm 1\ (mod\ 6)\:.$