# Remainder question without CRT

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility

If one knows the remainder of dividing a number $n$ by $2$ and $3$, is it possible to find and argument to know the remainder of dividing $n$ by $6$ without having to resort to the Chinese remainder theorem?

The converse (finding the remainders of dividing $n$ by $2$ and $3$ knowing the other one) is easy, but I'm not seeing a way to do this without using CRT.

Comment: Why do you want to avoid the very useful (and easy to understand) theorem ?

Comment: You can of course detect the bijection by taking the expressions $6k,6k+1,6k+2,6k+3,6k+4,6k+5$ modulo $2$ and $3$ , but this is basically the CRT for the case $(2,3)$

Comment: A proof'll be a special case of a CRT proof, e.g. by [Easy CRT](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/20259/242) in the  dupe, if $\,\color{#c00}{m\equiv 1\pmod{m'}}\,$ then 

$$\begin{align} 
n&\equiv a\!\!\pmod{m'}\\
n&\equiv b\!\!\pmod{m}\end{align}\iff  n \equiv\,\underbrace{ b+m\left[\dfrac{a-b}{\color{#c00}m}\color{#c00}{\bmod m'}\right]}_{\textstyle \bbox[5px,border:1px solid #c00]{ ma + (1-m)\:\!b}}\pmod{mm'}\qquad$$
OP is special case $\,m',m = 2,3.\ \ $

Comment: The point is - as explained [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2147772/242) - the Easy CRT formula is very easy to compute since one modulus $\,\color{#c00}{m}\,$ is $\color{#c00}{\equiv 1}$ mod the other $\,\color{#c00}{m'}\,$ so the fraction (inverse)  $\,(a-b)/m\equiv a-b \pmod {m'}$ in the Easy CRT formula is *trivial* to compute, so Easy CRT is even *easier* in this case.

Comment: If you know basic ring theory then it is possible to view this formula more conceptually in terms of the orthogonal idempotents yielding the direct product (Peirce) decomposition, e.g. see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/614256/242) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/894475/242).