# If $m$ and $n$ are relatively prime positive integers, prove that $m^{\phi(n)}+n^{\phi(m)}\equiv1\pmod{mn}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

I have found this question answered before but I am stuck going from

$$m^{\phi(n)}+n^{\phi(m)}\equiv1 \pmod{n}\\
n^{\phi(m)}+m^{\phi(n)}\equiv1 \pmod{m}$$
to
$$m^{\phi(n)}+n^{\phi(m)}\equiv1 \pmod{mn}$$

Why can we combine $\pmod{m}$ and $(\pmod{n}$ into $\pmod{mn}$? I know it's overall because $\gcd(m,n)=1$, but I don't understand why it is so. Is there a theorem for this specifically? I found this, but [this](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/GCD_from_Congruence_Modulo_m) seems to not multiply what is in the modulus together.

Here is the beginning of my proof:

$\gcd(m,n)=1\implies m^{\phi(n)}\equiv1 \pmod{n}$ and
$n^{\phi(m)}\equiv1 \pmod{m}$ by Euler's theorem.

$ m^{\phi(n)}\equiv1 \pmod{n} \equiv  m^{\phi(n)}+n^{\phi(m)}\equiv1+n^{\phi(m)}\pmod{n}$ and
$n^{\phi(m)}\equiv1 \pmod{m}\equiv n^{\phi(m)}+m^{\phi(n)}\equiv1+m^{\phi(n)} \pmod{m}$.

But $m^{\phi(n)} \equiv 0\pmod{m}$ and $n^{\phi(m)}\equiv 0\pmod{n}$.

So we have $m^{\phi(n)}+n^{\phi(m)}\equiv1\pmod{n}$ and $n^{\phi(m)}+m^{\phi(n)}\equiv1 \pmod{m}$...

... which implies $m^{\phi(n)}+n^{\phi(m)}\equiv1\pmod{mn}$.

Comment: See also [this answer.](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/134122/242)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From
$$m^{\phi(n)}+n^{\phi(m)}\equiv1 \pmod{n}\\
n^{\phi(m)}+m^{\phi(n)}\equiv1 \pmod{m}$$
we have
$$A=m^{\phi(n)}+n^{\phi(m)}-1= n\cdot q_1\\
A=n^{\phi(m)}+m^{\phi(n)}-1=m\cdot q_2$$
Effectively, same number $A$ is divisible by $m$ and $n$, where $\gcd(m,n)=1$. Thus $m\cdot n \mid A$ or $$m^{\phi(n)}+n^{\phi(m)}-1= n\cdot m \cdot q_3 \Rightarrow m^{\phi(n)}+n^{\phi(m)} \equiv 1 \pmod{mn}$$

---

All this is due to

**Proposition.** If $\gcd(m,n)=1$, $m \mid A$ and $n \mid A$ then $n\cdot m \mid A$.

Indeed
$$A=m\cdot q_1=\color{red}{n\cdot q_2} \tag{1}$$
and from [Bezout's lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zout%27s_identity) 
$$\exists x,y\in\mathbb{Z}: x\cdot m+y\cdot n=\gcd(m,n)=1$$
Altogether
$$x\cdot m\color{blue}{\cdot q_1}+y\cdot n\color{blue}{\cdot q_1}=\color{blue}{q_1} \overset{(1)}{\Rightarrow} \\ 
x\cdot \color{red}{n\cdot q_2}+y\cdot n\cdot q_1=q_1 \Rightarrow \\
n \mid q_1$$
or $A=m\cdot q_1=m\cdot n\cdot q_3$.