# Is some twin prime average the sum of two twin prime averages, two ways?

Tags: prime-numbers, conjectures, prime-gaps, open-problem, twin-primes

Accoring to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4644698/) and a linked duplicate, it's been verified empirically up to some number that all twin prime averages greater than six, are the sum of two smaller twin prime averages.

I was curious whether or not these formed a tree (with twin prime pairs at the vertices and the sum relation the edges).  In order for these to form a tree, for every twin prime average, we would only be able to find one pair of smaller twin prime averages which summed to it.

Can you find a counterexample, namely any twin prime average which is a sum of two smaller twin prime averages, more than one way?

Comment: What have you tried?  For example $60=30+30=42+18$ or $72=60+12=42+30$

Comment: I like your style.  Just because the tree is not uniquely defineable in a natural way, don't let that stop you from finding the missing proof!   Perhaps many trees is a blessing.  And thanks for linking to my post! :)

Comment: Here's another idea.  Form a Poset (partially ordered set) instead, it's kind of like a bunch of trees unioned together because they share nodes.  We say $x \leqslant y$ in the poset $P$ if and only if there exists another element $z \in P$ such that $x + z = y$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Number experiment finds a lot of counterexamples.

The smallest one is $71 + 73 = (11 + 13) + (59 + 61) = (29 + 31) + (41 + 43)$.

If we allow larger numbers, there can be a lot of ways: $$1877 + 1879 =\\ (5 + 7) + (1871 + 1873) =\\ (179 + 181) + (1697 + 1699) =\\ (269 + 271) + (1607 + 1609) =\\ (599 + 601) + (1277 + 1279) =\\ (827 + 829) + (1049 + 1051) =\\ (857 + 859) + (1019 + 1021)$$

Comment: Thanks for confirmation, I later realised this was already known to the original poster.