# Minimization of a piecewise affine function of $2$ variables

Tags: optimization

How does one minimize the following function?

$$f(x,y) = |kx + ly + c|$$

where $x,y \in \mathbb N$.

Comment: obivously this function is minimal if $f(x,y) = 0$. So the question reduces to finding all $(x,y)$ such that $kx + ly + c = 0$.

Comment: If x and y have to be integers, then f(x,y) will not always be minimized to 0. Example : k = 2, l= -2, c = -1.

Comment: Why is the question downvoted?

Comment: Have you considered adding constraints to make and equivalent constrained linear integer program? Otherwise, you have convex relaxations, so a simple branch and bound would work. Are you looking for/hoping for a closed form solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**What is going on?**

Let us first look at the real case:

[image: 2D view]
[image: 3D view]

We see that $f(x,y) = \lvert (k, l) (x,y)^\top + c \rvert$ results in a $V$ shaped surface. The reason is the "case distinction" of the absolute value function.

The valley line (the red line at $z=0$) is
$$
\frac{1}{\sqrt{k^2 + l^2}} (k, l) (x,y)^\top = \frac{-c}{\sqrt{k^2 + l^2}} = d
$$
where $(1/\sqrt{k^2 + l^2}) (k,l)^\top$ is a unit normal vector to the valley line (see the vector on the unit circle in the left graph) and $\lvert d \rvert$ is the distance to the origin (see the radius of the green circle and green sphere).

**Discrete case:**

For the discrete case we need to determine the intersections of $f$ with the grid $\mathbb{Z}^3$.

It should run down into coming up with the two planes that the $V$ is part of, stating the linear Diophantine equation there, and going for the smallest positive solution each, finally picking the smallest $z$-value of both cases.

**Determining the planes:**

The two linear Diophantine equations in three variables are 
$$
k x + l y - z = -c \\
k x + l y + z = -c 
$$
where the part intersecting with $f$ is characterized by $z \ge 0$.

Examples on how to solve such equations are given [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/514105/86776) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/581500/86776).

Comment: So, what does it mean?

Comment: I want to get an idea, what the parameters $k$, $l$, $c$ do influence.

Comment: Ohh okay. Suppose k,l,c are integers as large as 10^14 and greater than 0.

Comment: What about this : kx+ly  + c = P, and then kx+ly = P-c, and then see  what is the minimum P-c which is divided by gcd(k,l)... Will this work?

Comment: Your are faster asking than me trying to get a grip onto this problem :-)

Comment: Ohh sorry. I had thought of the above solution and so wanted to check if it was correct.