# How many positive integral solutions exist for $2a+3b-c = 0$ where $a$ ranges from $0$ to $5$, $b$ from $0$ to $10$ and $c$ from $0$ to $40$?

Tags: binomial-coefficients, diophantine-equations, integer-lattices, multinomial-coefficients

I was stuck with this particular problem. I tried finding a solution by attempting to find the coefficient of $x^0$ in $(1+x^2 +\dots+x^{10})(1+x^3 +\dots+x^{30})(1+x^{-1} +\dots+x^{-40})$ but for some reason was unsuccessful.  would appreciate it if someone could help me out with the approach to tackle this.

Answer (score 0):

We see that $c=2a+3b$, so the question is essentially asking how many $0\le a\le 5$ and $0\le b\le 10$ there are such that $0\le 2a+3b\le 40$.

For each value of $a$, we must have $b\le (40-2a)/3$ and $b\le 10$, and the number of $b$ which satisfies this is easily counted. One simply needs to add these numbers.

Answer (score 0):

this is called a lattice. On this site the tag is integer-lattices, and you explore that with https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/integer-lattices

The set of integers is parametrized as
$$ x(1,0,2) + y(0,1,3)  $$
That requires proof, but is true. See [On a homogeneous Diophantine equation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3692238/on-a-homogeneous-diophantine-equation/3693135#3693135)

As we get
$$ (x,y,2x+3y) $$
We just need the variables $x,y$ to obey the constraints on your $a,b,$  then check that $2x+3y$  does not exceed $40.$  Not to worry, $$   2 \cdot 5 + 3 \cdot 10 = 40 $$